# Not able login into Google account on Mac with correct password

Tags: macos, password, accounts, google

I am trying to login into my Google account in browser (tried Safari, Firefox, Chrome) on newly bought MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra 10.12.4) but getting 'Wrong password. Try again.' error every time, even though with same password, I am able to login on my Android phone and Windows laptop.

Found this article https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/3178296; 2-way auth is off on my account currently, tried this https://www.google.com/accounts/displayunlockcaptcha too, but still no success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes because an unknown character is being inserted while you are typing. To fix this, type your password on the TextEditor on your Mac and then copy and paste the password while logging into Gmail.

While pasting the password in Gmail you may have to use the keyboard shortcut, Command + V in case you are unable to right click.

Comment: Ya sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

You could try resetting a new password altogether, it's slightly extreme but that should certainly solve it for you.